# Grouby and count sum based on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe I have as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3],[2, 1],[2, 1],[3, 4],[3, 1],[3, 1],[3, 1],[3, 1],[4, 2],[4, 1],[4, 1],[4, 1]], columns=['id', 'count'])
df['date'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in 
              ['2016-12-28 15:17:00','2016-12-28 15:29:00','2017-01-05 09:32:00','2016-12-03 18:10:00','2016-12-10 11:31:00',
                '2016-12-14 09:32:00','2016-12-18 09:31:00','2016-12-22 09:32:00','2016-11-28 15:31:00','2016-12-01 16:11:00',
               '2016-12-10 09:31:00','2016-12-13 12:06:00']]
```

I would like to if grouby based on the condition: for the data has same `id`, if their date difference is less than 4 days, then consider them as same groups, otherwise create a new column `new_id`, then I will grouby and count sum based on `new_id`.

I have get the result with the following code, but it's too slow, how could I make it more effeciently?

```
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], ascending = [True, False], inplace = True)
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
df['id_up'] = df['id'].shift(-1)
df['id_down'] = df['id'].shift(1)
df['date_up'] = df['date'].shift(-1)       
df['date_diff'] = df.apply(lambda df: (df['date'] - df['date_up'])/datetime.timedelta(days=1) if df['id'] == df['id_up'] else 0, axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(['index','id_up','id_down','date_up'],axis=1)
df['new'] = ''
for i in range(df.shape[0]):   
    if i == 0:
        df.loc[i,'new'] = 1
    else:
        if df.loc[i,'id'] != df.loc[i-1,'id']:
            df.loc[i,'new'] = 1
        else:
            if df.loc[i-1,'date_diff'] <= 4:
                df.loc[i,'new'] = df.loc[i-1,'new']
            else:
                df.loc[i,'new'] = df.loc[i-1,'new'] + 1
df['new'] = df['id'].astype(str) + '-' +  df['new'].astype(str)
df1 = df.groupby('new')['date'].min()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.rename(columns={"date": "first_date"}, inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='new')
df1 = df.groupby('new')['date'].max()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.rename(columns={"date": "last_date"}, inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='new')
df1 = df.groupby('new')['count'].sum()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.rename(columns={"count": "count_sum"}, inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='new')
print(df)
```

Out:

```
    id  count         date      date_diff   new       first_date       last_date    count_sum
0   2   1   2017-01-05 09:32:00 7.752083    2-1 2017-01-05 09:32:00 2017-01-05 09:32:00 1
1   2   1   2016-12-28 15:29:00 0.008333    2-2 2016-12-28 15:17:00 2016-12-28 15:29:00 4
2   2   3   2016-12-28 15:17:00 0.000000    2-2 2016-12-28 15:17:00 2016-12-28 15:29:00 4
3   3   1   2016-12-22 09:32:00 4.000694    3-1 2016-12-22 09:32:00 2016-12-22 09:32:00 1
4   3   1   2016-12-18 09:31:00 3.999306    3-2 2016-12-10 11:31:00 2016-12-18 09:31:00 3
5   3   1   2016-12-14 09:32:00 3.917361    3-2 2016-12-10 11:31:00 2016-12-18 09:31:00 3
6   3   1   2016-12-10 11:31:00 6.722917    3-2 2016-12-10 11:31:00 2016-12-18 09:31:00 3
7   3   4   2016-12-03 18:10:00 0.000000    3-3 2016-12-03 18:10:00 2016-12-03 18:10:00 4
8   4   1   2016-12-13 12:06:00 3.107639    4-1 2016-12-10 09:31:00 2016-12-13 12:06:00 2
9   4   1   2016-12-10 09:31:00 8.722222    4-1 2016-12-10 09:31:00 2016-12-13 12:06:00 2
10  4   1   2016-12-01 16:11:00 3.027778    4-2 2016-11-28 15:31:00 2016-12-01 16:11:00 3
11  4   2   2016-11-28 15:31:00 0.000000    4-2 2016-11-28 15:31:00 2016-12-01 16:11:00 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `new` column you can do some thing like this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], ascending = [True, False], inplace = True)
groups = df.groupby('id')

# mask where the date differences exceed threshold    
df['new'] = groups.date.diff().abs() > pd.to_timedelta(4, unit='D')

# group within each id
df['new'] = groups['new'].cumsum().astype(int) + 1

# concatenate `id` and `new`:
df['new'] = df['id'].astype(str) + '-' + df['new'].astype(str)

# get other columns with groupby
new_groups = df.groupby('new')

df['first_date'] = new_groups.date.transform('min')
df['last_date'] = new_groups.date.transform('max')
df['count_sum'] = new_groups['count'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
      id    count  date                 new    first_date           last_date              count_sum
--  ----  -------  -------------------  -----  -------------------  -------------------  -----------
 0     2        1  2017-01-05 09:32:00  2-1    2017-01-05 09:32:00  2017-01-05 09:32:00            1
 1     2        1  2016-12-28 15:29:00  2-2    2016-12-28 15:17:00  2016-12-28 15:29:00            4
 2     2        3  2016-12-28 15:17:00  2-2    2016-12-28 15:17:00  2016-12-28 15:29:00            4
 3     3        1  2016-12-22 09:32:00  3-1    2016-12-22 09:32:00  2016-12-22 09:32:00            1
 4     3        1  2016-12-18 09:31:00  3-2    2016-12-10 11:31:00  2016-12-18 09:31:00            3
 5     3        1  2016-12-14 09:32:00  3-2    2016-12-10 11:31:00  2016-12-18 09:31:00            3
 6     3        1  2016-12-10 11:31:00  3-2    2016-12-10 11:31:00  2016-12-18 09:31:00            3
 7     3        4  2016-12-03 18:10:00  3-3    2016-12-03 18:10:00  2016-12-03 18:10:00            4
 8     4        1  2016-12-13 12:06:00  4-1    2016-12-10 09:31:00  2016-12-13 12:06:00            2
 9     4        1  2016-12-10 09:31:00  4-1    2016-12-10 09:31:00  2016-12-13 12:06:00            2
10     4        1  2016-12-01 16:11:00  4-2    2016-11-28 15:31:00  2016-12-01 16:11:00            3
11     4        2  2016-11-28 15:31:00  4-2    2016-11-28 15:31:00  2016-12-01 16:11:00            3
```

Comment: Thank you, why `count_sum` of `df['new']=='2-1'` is `3` in the output?

Comment: I forgot `sort_values` as in your solution. Also, change `diff(-1)` to `diff()` matches your output. See edits.

Comment: Soory, one more problem, instead of `df['count_sum'] = new_groups['count'].transform('sum')`, I think I need ignore `cout` and use `df['count_sum'] = df.groupby('new')['id'].transform('size')`, but new column `count_sum` are `NaN`s, any ideas?

Comment: `transform('size')` should not give any `NaN`. I got `1,2,2,1,3,3,3...` for the sample data. Did you use `transform` or `apply`?

Comment: I re-tested the code, it works right now. Strange. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, the `groupby` can take a function that transforms row index to group by labels, and it is called iteratively on each row. By using this, we can do the following:

```
# sort dataframe by id and date in ascending order
df = df.sort_values(["id", "date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

# global variable for convenience of demonstration
lastid = maxdate = None
groupid = 0
def grouper(rowidx):
    global lastid, maxdate, groupid
    row = df.loc[rowidx]
    if lastid != row['id'] or maxdate < row['date']:
        # see next group
        lastid = row['id']
        maxdate = row['date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
        groupid += 1
    return groupid

# use grouper to split df into groups
for id, group in df.groupby(grouper):
    print("[%s]" % id)
    print(group)
```

The output of the above using your `df` is:

```
[1]
   id  count                date
0   2      3 2016-12-28 15:17:00
1   2      1 2016-12-28 15:29:00
[2]
   id  count                date
2   2      1 2017-01-05 09:32:00
[3]
   id  count                date
3   3      4 2016-12-03 18:10:00
[4]
   id  count                date
4   3      1 2016-12-10 11:31:00
5   3      1 2016-12-14 09:32:00
[5]
   id  count                date
6   3      1 2016-12-18 09:31:00
[6]
   id  count                date
7   3      1 2016-12-22 09:32:00
[7]
   id  count                date
8   4      2 2016-11-28 15:31:00
9   4      1 2016-12-01 16:11:00
[8]
    id  count                date
10   4      1 2016-12-10 09:31:00
11   4      1 2016-12-13 12:06:00
```

and you can make an arbitrary group-by logic using this mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
interval_date = 4

groups = df.groupby('id')

# interval_date = pd.to_timedelta(4, unit='D')

df['date_diff_down'] = groups.date.diff(-1).abs()/timedelta(days=1)
df = df.fillna(method='ffill') 

df['date_diff_up'] = groups.date.diff(1).abs()/timedelta(days=1)
df = df.fillna(method='bfill')

df['data_chunk_mark'] = df.apply(lambda df: 0 if df['date_diff_up'] < interval_date else 1, axis=1)
groups = df.groupby('id')

df['new_id'] = groups['data_chunk_mark'].cumsum().astype(int) + 1

df['new_id'] = df['id'].astype(str) + '-' + df['new_id'].astype(str)

new_groups = df.groupby('new_id')

# df['first_date'] = new_groups.date.transform('min')
# df['last_date'] = new_groups.date.transform('max')
df['count_sum'] = new_groups['count'].transform('sum')
print(df)
```

Out:

```
    id  count                date  date_diff_down  date_diff_up  \
1    2      1 2017-01-05 09:32:00        7.752083      7.752083   
2    2      1 2016-12-28 15:29:00        0.008333      7.752083   
0    2      3 2016-12-28 15:17:00        0.008333      0.008333   
7    3      1 2016-12-22 09:32:00        4.000694      4.000694   
6    3      1 2016-12-18 09:31:00        3.999306      4.000694   
5    3      1 2016-12-14 09:32:00        3.917361      3.999306   
4    3      1 2016-12-10 11:31:00        6.722917      3.917361   
3    3      4 2016-12-03 18:10:00        6.722917      6.722917   
11   4      1 2016-12-13 12:06:00        3.107639      3.107639   
10   4      1 2016-12-10 09:31:00        8.722222      3.107639   
9    4      1 2016-12-01 16:11:00        3.027778      8.722222   
8    4      2 2016-11-28 15:31:00        3.027778      3.027778   

    data_chunk_mark new_id  count_sum  
1                 1    2-2          1  
2                 1    2-3          4  
0                 0    2-3          4  
7                 1    3-2          1  
6                 1    3-3          3  
5                 0    3-3          3  
4                 0    3-3          3  
3                 1    3-4          4  
11                0    4-1          2  
10                0    4-1          2  
9                 1    4-2          3  
8                 0    4-2          3
```